# How to show error message on client side when press delete button without selecting checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

When I am not selecting `checkbox` in my `gridview` and press delete button it show error "No Check box has been selected" but when after that when i select `checkbox` and click on delete button it still showing that error don't knw why?
i am not using any database i just use `datatable` and `gridview`.

Here is my code on delete button

```
protected void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];

    if (dt == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    List<DataRow> rowsToDelete = new List<DataRow>();
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
        {
            row.Visible = false;

            //remove row by its index as it should GridViewRow index == DataRow index
            //it is not the best way but from your code I dont have information how your GridView looks
            dt.Rows.RemoveAt(row.RowIndex);

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            GridView2.DataSource = dt;
            GridView2.DataBind();

            ViewState["CurrentData"] = dt;
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Visible = true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rowsToDelete.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Remove(rowsToDelete[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you debug? could it be that `CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");` result in `cb` being null

Comment: yes its null mate @bas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run this code.

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    var dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];

    if (dt == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox2");
        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
        {
            Label1.Visible = false;
            dt.Rows.RemoveAt(row.RowIndex);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            GridView2.DataSource = dt;
            GridView2.DataBind();

            ViewState["CurrentData"] = dt;
        }
        else if (cb.Checked == false)
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: And also paste this line on Page_Load function. Label1.Visible = false;

Comment: There is no `Label1` in the question. Do you know something more about the OP's code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{

}
```

function on page load

Comment: if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  //put your code here which you use to bind grid view
}

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> lblError.Visible = true;
> ```

Once you set the control to visible, all postbacks will remember that the control is visible and will continue showing the control. You have two options:

- Explicitly set `lblError.Visible = false;` in your code when there is no error.
- Change `lblError` in your `.aspx` file to set `EnableViewState` to `false`.

Actually, looking closer: your logic has other issues that need to be resolved as well. You check each row, and if *any* row has its checkbox unchecked, you set `lblError.Visible` to `true`. Based on the text of your `lblError`, you need to only make it visible when *all* rows have their checkboxes unchecked.

```
bool allUnchecked = true;
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
    if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
    {
        /* your existing code here */

        allUnchecked = false;
    }
    /* no else branch here */

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsToDelete.Count; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Remove(rowsToDelete[i]);
    }
}
lblError.Visible = allUnchecked;
```

Comment: Its showing an error message: Error 1 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'Visible' and no extension method 'Visible' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Amitesh\WebBased\Default4.aspx.cs 126 33 E:\...\WebBased\

Comment: @amitesh Did you accidentally type something like `lblError.Visible.Visible = false;`, perhaps? `lblError` shouldn't be a `bool`, and if the code in your question compiles, it isn't a `bool`.

Comment: @amitesh I think there are more problems with your code, please take a look at my edit and see if it makes sense to you.